# How can I get a space in my Minecraft username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen other people with spaces in their names and I'm not sure how I can, as well. I know that you can't do this just by changing your name, as Mojang doesn't allow it.

Is there any way I can?

Comment: I posted an answer addressing the reasons behind this, but in hindsight I believe asking to circumvent security measures of any kind is not allowed here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for help circumventing a game's policy.

Comment: @Joachim I don't think that close reason applies because they didn't realize they were trying to circumvent a policy.

Comment: @pppery I take the "Mojang doesn't allow it" as an admittance of this, but it might not have been, indeed. I'll wait to see how others react, and undeleted my answer for now.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open for the same reason pppery said.  I don't think the OP was trying to circumvent anything and was purely curious on if its possible.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't** (in Java Edition<sup>*</sup>).

During alpha there seemed to have been even more leeway when it came to creating usernames, allowing users to include dots and spaces, and have names consisting of two characters ([source](https://hypixel.net/threads/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-illegal-minecraft-name.3597033/post-25822747)).

And it was apparently possible for longer to get a space as the first or last character of a username (source), which is perhaps corroborated by [this old official Minecraft page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210821193612/https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034636712-Minecraft-Usernames):

> No Spaces are allowed between characters [but compare to the "No spaces" requirement [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513205755/https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034636712-Minecraft-Usernames)]

This got fixed, however, probably after Minecraft left alpha. Only much later, in 2020, was this followed up by a username "purge", when Mojang started to go through the list of usernames and renaming those with invalid characters (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el8fMxZi8YA), for instance).

Spaces in usernames are especially annoying for moderators, as they have no way to target those using commands (see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/276wcb/psa_usernames_can_contain_spaces_this_effectively/), for example) and make it much harder to ban those users (hence an illegal trade in those usernames, see e.g. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w3JmZ13bqA)).

---

<sup>* In Bedrock it is allowed.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Whatever you saw was probably a team prefix, a custom scoreboard display (1.21+) or something from a mod.